# BLTouch with TH3D Ender 3 pro

Tags: creality-ender-3, bltouch, th3d

I installed TH3D to my stock mainboard via [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TTuisjmbmY&list=WL&index=47&t=0s), but BLTouch does not work properly.

It does not check all 9 points before point it just go middle then check z then start printing. BLTouch normally needs to check all 9 points before printing or with autobedleveling but somehow mine do not work like this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Did you insert `G29` in your start G-code script?

Comment: Hey, yes after a while I understand it and find a gcode that is suitable for ender 3 and bltouch now it seems working fine. Ty for your respond :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting up the BLTouch in firmware, you need to activate the leveling function for every print by inserting the leveling G-code ['G29'](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#G29:_Detailed_Z-Probe) in the start G-code script of your slicer. The code should be placed directly after command `G28`.

Note that you can test the working of the sensor from the printer display: sensor can be deployed, stowed, reset and tested.

An alternative is to use the `G29` and `M500` command once in a while (for beds that don't change, don't get handled by excessive force and/or are operated at the same temperature) or store the shape of the bed through the display interface and put the command [`M420 S1`](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M420:_Leveling_On.2FOff.2FFade_.28Marlin.29) in your start G-code instead.