# Ender 3 V2 bed slanted

Tags: creality-ender-3, octoprint, creality

I'm at a loss I have no idea what to do, I've tried everything I can think of. I've fixed my x-axis gantry, added silicon bed mounts, used washers, straightened out my BLTouch but still this is the result when I create a mesh:

[image: The result]

I did recently order the solid bed mounts from TH3D, could the silicon ones I got on Amazon be the issue? Also I’m using Octoprint bed level visualizer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! With `straightened out my BLTouch` you mean that you re-leveled the bed prior to printing, i.e. you did not mount the silicone bushings and went printing directly? Plus side is that the bed is straight! it is just tilted mainly in Y-axis direction.

Comment: Oscar is one who can help.  See https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/16604/automatic-bed-leveling-abl-with-a-sensor-bltouch-inductive-capacitive-how

Comment: @0scar what i mean is the BLTouch bracket was at a slight angle so I fixed it. And I haven’t printed yet I mounted the bushings and tried leveling. And how would I fix the y axis tilt?