# Anycubic Mega X slanted Z-axis

Tags: z-axis, anycubic-i3-mega

Just got a new printer (first time setting it up myself).

While trying to level it, it appeared that the left side was higher than the right on the Z-axis. When the nozzle moves left, it digs into the platform. I checked the Z-stop sensor on the right side and it appears that when the screw hits it, the motor doesn't stop like it's supposed to.

After a few tries, the screw has managed to push the lever out to the side. I'm not great with tech, anyone have suggestions?

Comment: I don't have automatice bed leveling, but Oscar has a page here: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/16604/automatic-bed-leveling-abl-with-a-sensor-bltouch-inductive-capacitive-how

Comment: The Z-axis is usually the up/down movement, X-axis is left/right, and Y-axis is front/back. Your question sounds more like it is the X-axis, can you confirm this please?

Comment: Could you [edit] and add a photo or two in order to illustrate the issue better? Maybe of the errant screw, and the pushed out lever...