# BLTouch collides with side of bed when starting print AFTER leveling

Tags: creality-ender-3, bltouch

Okay, this one is a bit weird as everything else on the printer (for the most part at least...) is working perfectly. Some minor adjustments here and there are needed but this issue has shown up recently since adding a BLTouch.

After starting the print my printer regardless if I have it set up to wipe or not will them run the BLTouch (NOT the extruder, ONLY the BLTouch) into the side of the print bed. All of my offsets seem to be correct but for whatever reason, I can't seem to figure out what to correct to make this not run into the side of the bed as admittedly after the collision it prints fine! Any ideas?

(I have provided a video to give a better idea as to what exactly is going on as there are similar issues however they don't quite match my situation from what I've seen)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not **after** leveling, but **during** leveling when probing the first point of the mesh. As it fails to detect the trigger point, it skips further levelling steps. As the probe doesn't retract it is bound to cause a problem.

This could potentially be a non-genuine Antclabs touch probe, which are of lower quality than the original Antclabs BLTouch. The original BLTouch has a screw on top which might be present here also, you could try to adjust it for it to retract better on triggering (see [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/16605/) for some more information on the working of a touch sensor). The screw attracts the magnet on the top of the probe pin, getting the screw closer (clockwise) to increase the attraction and thus make it easier to attract it back up when retracting.

If the probe retracts in the middle of the bed, it should retract at every point on the bed. If it does not retract, there is something wrong with the sensor. You could insert an additional spacer (0.5 - 1 mm) between the mount and the probe to make a little more distance between the nozzle and the probe.

---

Could be the angle of the video, but make sure the frame is at 90° angles and the bed is as level as possible. Note that when using a sheet of glass, it generally is not required to use a touch sensor for scanning the surface, glass is flat. You could check with a ruler on its side. Basically, `G29` can be skipped by taking it out of the start G-code, the sensor will than only be used in the middle of the bed to home Z.

Comment: I would note this is the genuine Creality BL touch so dunno about any issues there as the orignal bltouch I had catastrophic issues with oroginally I'll see about skiping G29 though and see if it solves my issue thanks